# Optimizing python loops for millions of rows

Tags: python, optimization, faker

I'm trying to simulate test datasets using Python-Faker. The goal is to have a few million records for my use-case. Following is the code I use to populate 5 data elements for 1 Million records.

```py
for i in range(500000):
    df = df.append(
        {'COL1': fake.first_name_female(),
         'COL2': fake.last_name_female(),
         'COL3': 'F',
         'COL4': fake.street_address(),
         'COL5': fake.zipcode_in_state()
         }, ignore_index=True)
    df = df.append(
        {'COL1': fake.first_name_male(),
         'COL2': fake.last_name_male(),
         'COL3': 'M',
         'COL4': fake.street_address(),
         'COL5': fake.zipcode_in_state()
         }, ignore_index=True)
```

It took nearly 8 hours to run this. How could I optimize this loop to run faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from time import time
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

def fake_row(i):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        row = [fake.first_name_female(), fake.last_name_female(), 'F', fake.street_address(), fake.zipcode_in_state()]
    else:
        row = [fake.first_name_male(), fake.last_name_male(), 'M', fake.street_address(), fake.zipcode_in_state()]
    return row

start = time()
fake_data = [fake_row(i) for i in range(500000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(fake_data, columns=['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3', 'COL4', 'COL5'])
print('[TIME]', time() - start)
[TIME] 171.82 secs
```

Need faster code? Use `deco`

```
import pandas as pd
from time import time
from faker import Faker
from deco import concurrent, synchronized
fake = Faker()

@concurrent
def fake_row(i):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        row = [fake.first_name_female(), fake.last_name_female(), 'F', fake.street_address(), fake.zipcode_in_state()]
        return row
    else:
        row = [fake.first_name_male(), fake.last_name_male(), 'M', fake.street_address(), fake.zipcode_in_state()]
        return row

@synchronized
def run(size):
    res = []
    for i in range(size):
        res.append(fake_row(i))
    return pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3', 'COL4', 'COL5'])

start = time()
df = run(500000)
print('[TIME]', time() - start)
[TIME] 88.11 secs
```

Comment: This works perfectly, one small correction, I need to iterate this to '1000000' instead of  '500000'.

Comment: @Nariman Yes. Because you need alternative male and female. This is just representational.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that you have enough RAM and that your Operating System is using HD Space as RAM?

Swaping/Paging, can reduce the speed of any running software (and the entire OS) as code demands more and more memory while the operating system is try to use more and more of the free HD Space to allocate more and more "virtual" RAM space on the HD after all/almost all the space on your "physical" RAM has been exhausted...

Run the code, and keep monitoring the memory consumption of the code while the code is running.

If you are on Mac OS X: go to Applications -> Activity Monitor -> Memory (tab)

Comment: I think it's not a memory issue. If you see the code, appending every time to a data frame takes time and even faker is slow.

Comment: I do not disagree with you...  i just wanted to make sure the memory issue is not overlooked... Maybe i should have written that in a comment rather than an answer!

Comment: You have explained it very well. If Memory is an issue, it'll help him/community. Leave it as is.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! It is definitely not the memory, as @Vishnudev pointed, appending every iteration is the issue.